# dlopen / dlsym with as little linking as possible

Tags: c, dynamic, linker, dlopen

I have an application which can make use of plugins which are loaded at runtime using dlopen. Each of the plugins defines a function toretrieve the plugin information which is defined using a common structure. Something like that:

```
struct plugin {
    char *name;
    char *app_version;
    int app_verion_id;
    char *plugin_version;
    int plugin_version_id;
    /* ... */
 };

 struct plugin p = { "sample plugin",APP_VERION,APP_VERSION_ID,"1.2.3",10203 };

 struct plugin *get_plugin() {
     return &p;
 }
```

This works well and plugins can be loaded. Now i want to build a small tool to read these properties without linking the whole application. For doing that I have some code like this:

```
void *handle;
struct plugin *plugin;
struct plugin *(get_plugin*)();

handle = dlopen(filename, RTLD_LAZY);
if (!handle) { /*...return; ...*/ }

get_plugin = dlym(handle, "get_plugin");
if (!get_plugin) { /*...return; ...*/ }

plugin = get_plugin();
printf("Plugin: %s\n", plugin->name);
```

This works nice for simple plugins. The issue is that many plugins reference further symbols from the application, which are resolved even though RTLD_LAZY was set. (like global variables from the application which are used to initialize plugin-global things) So the dlopen() call fails with an error like `fatal: relocation error: file sample_plugin.so: symbol application_some_symbol: referenced symbol not found`. As I just want to have access to the single simple structure I was wondering how I can prevent the linker from doing that much of his work.

Comment: What link options do you use when building the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using elf binaries you may want to see if your platform has libelf available.
Try `man elf` for more info.  This may get you what you need without having to actually link.  I have never used it though, so I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, based on an  example from Solaris' gelf(3ELF) man page I created a small tool which, on the fly, generates a .so with all needed symbols, then loads this .so and then dlopen()'s my plugin. a bit hackish but works :-)
(probably I might have done that with a shell script paring ldd output, too ... but works for now and I can organize my plugins here)

Comment: Well, you're probably smarter than me to have made that tool.  Very interesting.  Glad I could be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man dlopen` (emphasis is mine)

> RTLD_LAZY
>
> Perform  lazy  binding.
> Only  resolve symbols as the code that
> references them is executed.  If the
> symbol is never referenced, then  it
> is never resolved.  **(Lazy binding is
> only performed for function
> references; references to variables
> are always  immediately bound when the
> library is loaded.)**

So you need to add to your tool all the global variables your plugin might use.

Comment: Yeah, I hoped somebody would have an idea for a work-around :-/

Answer (score 0):

How about a dirty hack with `objdump`:

```
~$ objdump -s -j .rodata plugin.so  

plugin.so:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .rodata:
 20000000 73616d70 6c652070 6c756769 6e00332e  sample plugin.3.
 20000010 322e3100 312e322e 3300               2.1.1.2.3.
```